# SQLite get value from DB

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am trying to make query from DB in the following way

```
public Cursor getManagementData() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_STAFF + " WHERE " + DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT + " GLOB " + "'management'";

    return db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

}
```

The same thing I have tried with

```
query(DBHelper.TABLE_STAFF, new String[] {
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_POSITION,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT, DBHelper.COLUMN_PICTURE }, null,
            new String[] { "management" }, null, null, null);
```

but nothing happens.

The table structure is very simple: Table `staff` with Column `department` and I want to get all entries named `management`.

If you will not be able to answer, please recommend where to find close solution because after googling I have not found any comprehensive examples on searching DB by entries whether with rawQuery or just query.

Thank you in advance.

I have made changes recomended by Mr.Choy it does not crashes but when open in my app list is empty. At the same time when I run the following query:

```
    public Cursor getEmployeesData() {

    return db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_STAFF, new String[] {
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_POSITION,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT, DBHelper.COLUMN_PICTURE }, null,
            null, null, null, null);

}
```

it shows all data as it should be.

Could it be the problem with cursor adapter def. I use:

```
        String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_POSITION, DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_PICTURE };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3,
            R.id.textView4, R.id.imageView1 };
```

Comment: why in first function you don't have equal?

Comment: it says syntax error. What about just query. What am I doing wrong. And do you know any sites where I can find comprehensive info on query use.

Answer (score 1):

I think your raw query is wrong. It should be

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_STAFF 
    + " WHERE " + DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT + "='management'";
```

You can take a look at basic SQL query syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: @user1706819 What is the value of `DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT`?

Comment: @user1706819 Are you sure the value is management? It defines a table column name which should be something like `department`. I suspect it is causing error in the SQL, thats why I am asking it's value.

Comment: public static final String COLUMN_DEPARTMENT = "department";

Comment: sorry, I did not get your question. I thought you are asking about value to be retireved.

Comment: @user1706819 Then the query should be fine. You can take a look at the link I provided in the answer, hope that helps you solve the problem!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41690/discussion-between-user1706819-and-lawrence-choy)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot equal statement in your function use this:

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_STAFF + " WHERE " + 
    DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT + "='management'";
```

DBHelper.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT must be your colomn name and management must be the value in colomn that you want

you can read this [Article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) and [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/where.php) for more information of basic SQL query

Comment: I saw Vogel's example and find his resource as very valuable for new developers like me. But he does'not provide any examples on quering by values